# Jest, Typescript, ts-jest: Coverage is slightly incorrect

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am wrtiting a project using TypeScript, Jest and the `ts-jest` NPM module.

When I run my test, I do get some amount of coverage, but the HTML report is not quite right:

[image: Code coverage issues]

Furthermore, some functions are being marked as untested even though they are certainly being called.

My package.json is set as follows:

```
{
    "jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "testResultsProcessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/coverageprocessor.js",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "json"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Did you look in `coverage/remapped/html/index.html`?

Comment: THANK YOU! Can you post this as a response so that I can mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Starting from jest@20 you can pass [mapCoverage](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#mapcoverage-boolean) option and use `coverage/lcov-report/index.html` file.

**OLD**

I also have been struggling with this problem, but then I notice [that line](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/src/coverageprocessor.ts#L75).

Long story short - coverage reports goes to `coverage/remapped/html/index.html` file.

Comment: Is there any way to use the remapped output in the console, instead of the "slightly-off" one?

Comment: @JarrodMosen currently it's impossible, see https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/42#issuecomment-256792842

Comment: Note [mapCoverage has now been removed from jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/340)

Comment: @mikemaccana did u found an alternative ?

Comment: @SkyzohKey Sorry, I'm on a new project now.