# How can I get coverage maps using current ts-jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Similar to [Jest, Typescript, ts-jest: Coverage is slightly incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188484/jest-typescript-ts-jest-coverage-is-slightly-incorrect) - however the answer there applies to older versions of jest where the `mapCoverage` option existed.

[`mapCoverage` has now been removed](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/340) and my impression is that ts-jest should now provide coverage reports that work out of the box.

I have followed the [ts-jest documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/installation) to install and run ts-jest:

```
npm install --save-dev jest typescript ts-jest @types/jest
npx ts-jest config:init
npx jest --coverage --coverageDirectory='coverage'
open coverage/lcov-report/index.ts.html
```

However I can see that the coverage report generates incorrect maps:

[image]

**How can I get coverage maps using current ts-jest?**

I have tried adding `collectCoverage: true` to my `jest.config.js` which has not changed the output.

Comment: Hi @mikemaccana, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to specify:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      "sourceMap": true,
```

in your `tsconfig.json` file?

This solved the problem for me.

Versions:

- node 14.17.0
- typescript: 4.5.4
- ts-jest: 27.1.2
- jest: 27.4.5

Comment: Ah you're right! [`sourceMap` defaults to `false`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#sourceMap) which causes `ts-jest` to show bad coverage maps and inaccurate code positions for errors.